# Oracle Grant privileges

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

How do I grant privileges to a user so they can pass the privileges to another user in Oracle?

Grant All On Customers to Admin;

is this command work?

Thanks

Comment: You could find this [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#i2062275).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need the `with grant option` clause.

```
grant all
   on customer
   to some_user
 with grant option;
```

If you were granting a system privilege rather than an object privilege, use the `with admin option` clause instead of `with grant option`.

Answer (score 2):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.customers TO username WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `WITH GRANT OPTION`:

```
Grant All On Customers to Admin with grant option;
```